# How can I increase the font size using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying:

```
    $('a[data-text="size-bigger"]').click(function ()
      {
        a=$('span');
        b=$('span').css('font-size');
        a.css('font-size', b+1);
      }
    );
```

I had it working fine for just directly setting the size. Now I am trying to make it relative based on the previous size, i.e. "zoomable" - click the link and the spans increase in size, but it has no effect, what might be wrong ?

Comment: font size is returned as a string, including the unit, such as `1.3em`, so adding an int won't work. You would need to get the value of the string, increment it as required, then piece it back together with the unit. This is obvously assuming the unit may change. If it is always the same unit, it would be much easier as you can simply use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` and append the unit back on.

Comment: do you want to be able to simply increment the size or jump between pre selected sizes as happens in Word?  if you want to jump between pre set sizes you could use an array of values and just search for the next larger value

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('a[data-text="size-bigger"]').click(function(){
        a=$('span');
        b=parseInt($('span').css('font-size'));
        b=b + 1 + "px";
        a.css({'font-size':b});
});
```

`$('span').css('font-size')` is going to give you a string (ex. `12px`). If you want to increment the number, you'll need to extract the number from that string with `parseInt()`. `parseInt('12px')` will give you `12`, which you can increment (`13`) and, after you add `px` back, you can set the `font-size` to your newly incremented number.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/5G6W6/315/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt to get the Integervalue of the font-size attribute:

```
$('a[data-text="size-bigger"]').click(function(){
    a = $('span');
    var fontSize = $('span').css('font-size').val();
    var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize.replace('px','')) + 1 + 'px';
    a.css({'font-size':newFontSize});
});
```

I'm not sure if you have to replace the `px` or `em` with `''` or it will work without this. Give it a try ;)